# join multiple png images

Tags: macos, terminal, preview, image-editing

Often I find myself needing to take many PNG images and join them into a larger image.

Specifically, in this particular case, I'd like to take 2 PNGs of roughly equal width (±2px) and different heights and create a new PNG where the first is above the other. E.g.

[image]

The join should be seamless.

Is there a command line tool/app that does this? Best would be if Preview offers a solution.

Comment: [`sips`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) is the closest thing I know of, but I don't think this'll do what you want. Anything wrong with using a photo editing program like GIMP?

Comment: @JMY1000 I'm hoping there's a native method or some simple one-liner terminal script. Using GIMP to do this simple task takes forever (starting up GIMP, creating new image of correct dimensions, pasting in the two PNGs.) Maybe there's a specialist app that isn't native to macOS, I wouldn't mind installing it if there was.

Comment: Fair enough. Not aware of anything off the top of my head.

Comment: In your OP you said, "Best would be if Preview offers a solution.", Preview doesn't have that functionality and neither does `sips` as mention in the comments. In your comment you said, "I'm hoping there's a native method or some simple one-liner terminal script", there is no native method that I know of, but that does't mean there isn't. The third-party app ImageMagic has a `montage` command to create a composite image by combining several separate images. You might have to first rotate the images using some other command of ImageMagic, or `sips`. Can't say for sure as I've not used it.

Comment: @user3439894 I already have ImageMagick installed, I'll look into the montage command. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ImageMagick can do this:

```
convert 1.png 2.png -append result.png
```

Alignment options can be (optionally) specified using the `-gravity` switch,

- `-gravity East` align the right edges
- `-gravity West` align the left edges
- `-gravity center` align the centers

Note: using `+append` instead of `-append` will stitch the images together horizontally (side-by-side) rather than one above the other.

Comment: +1 for coming back to share that ImageMagick could do this and how you did it. :)

Comment: Is there anyway to link some gui type interaction here? I find most of the time I want to convert screenshots with long names that are hard to distinguish between effectively at the command line. It would be nice if I could pick the images I want combined via finder, and then the rest of this script runs.

Comment: @Rey type `convert` and then drag and drop the files from finder into terminal

Comment: @Rey — I added an answer to address your question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/395488/136164

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this entirely in Finder, you can create an Automator service and run it as a Service through the right-click menu.

1. open Automator.app
2. **New** > **Service**
3. **Service receives selected** "Image Files" in "Finder.app"
4. add **Utilities** > **Run Shell Script**
5. enter the script shown below (include the trailing newline)
6. **Save** as "Image Append - Vertical" (saves to ~/Library/Services/Image Append - Vertical.workflow)

To run — select two or more images in Finder, right-click > **Services** > **Image Append - Vertical**

A new file will be created with the name of the first image suffixed with "v" before the file extension.

Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=$(dirname -- "$1")
FILE=$(basename -- "$1")
NAME="${FILE%.*}"
EXT="${FILE##*.}"
# call ImageMagick with selected files and create new file with "v" suffix
convert "$@" -append "${DIR}/${NAME}v.${EXT}"
# GraphicsMagick version (smaller & faster than ImageMagick)
#/opt/local/bin/gm convert "$@" -append "${DIR}/${NAME}v.${EXT}"
```

Automator screenshot (macOS High Sierra):

[image: Automator.app screenshot]